# the react-test-library mock click event is not working?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

a simple test case :
testClick.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'antd'

export default function testClick() {
  const onClick = () =>{
    console.log("2333")
  }
  return (
    <Button onClick={onClick}>testClick</Button>
  )
}
```

testClick.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import TestClick from './testClick'
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
const onClick = jest.fn()
describe('partnerModal UI', () => {
  test('partnerModal UI', async () => {
    const { findByText } = await render(<TestClick />)
    const authEl = await findByText('testClick')
    await fireEvent.click(authEl)
    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

when i run this case , I account a error,I'm confuse that `console.log` has been invoke, but the on Search is not hasbeencall? why？

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a mock `onClick` function but didn't pass it into the component and call it inside the `onClick` function. So the mock `onClick` function wasn't called, that's why.

Besides, check mocked function has been called or not is testing the implementation details that is **not** a recommended test strategy.

The recommended test strategy is testing the behavior of the component. When the `click` event happened, some state of the component may be changed, you should check what the component renders after the state changes.

But the code you provided, `onClick` didn't do anything, but just called `console.log` to print a string. The code does not have much practical significance. The only you can do is assert `console.log` is to be called or not.

```
import React from 'react';
import TestClick from './testClick';
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('partnerModal UI', () => {
  test('partnerModal UI', async () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const { findByText } = await render(<TestClick />)
    const authEl = await findByText('testClick')
    await fireEvent.click(authEl)
    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    logSpy.mockStore();
  })
});
```